# How to set form input value based on 2 previously selected values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, multiple-conditions, calculation

I am working on a taxi service pre-booking form and I have a price list based on routes between specific postcodes and airports.

When someone is booking, he/she selects the airport and then the postcode from where the transfer is required.

Let's say that the selected airport is Heathrow and the postcode is N1 xx. I know the price between N1 and Heathrow, so as soon as someone selects this combination in the form and presses the button to get a fare, I want to display the matched price.

I was thinking of using JavaScript, but I seek help.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  jQuery( "estimateNext" ).click(function() { 
      var froma = jQuery("Transferfrom").val();
      var toa =  jQuery("Transferto").val();

      if (froma == "Heathrow" && toa == "N1")
      {
          jQuery("Total").val("38");    
      }
      elseif (froma == "Heathrow" && toa == "N2") {
          jQuery("Total").val("40");
      }
  }
</script>
```

I'm creating the form in Joomla with a component.

I could create tables in the database for the prices, if that was required.

Comment: you can use jquery ajax and the append() http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: You can create json tree like `{"Heathrow": [{"N1": 38}, {"N2": 40}] }` and then on change print options.